# IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready & IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): xenbr2: link is not ready on Ubuntu Server - Xen bridge

Tags: ubuntu, xen, bridge, ifconfig

Hi all,
I am having some problems getting a Xen bridge up in Ubuntu precise with Xen.
I created a first bridge on eth1 with no problems, but the exact same process for eth2 yields the following problems:

> **/etc/network/interfaces**
>
> auto xenbr1 
> iface xenbr1inet manual
> bridge_ports eth1
> bridge_fd 9
> bridge_hello 2
> bridge_maxage 12
> bridge_stp off
>
> auto xenbr2
> iface xenbr2 inet manual
> bridge_ports eth2
> bridge_fd 9
> bridge_hello 2
> bridge_maxage 12
> bridge_stp off

---

> **ifup xenbr2**
> Waiting for xenbr2 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 20 seconds).
> ssh stop/waiting
> ssh start/running, process 10377
> (Takes quite a while)

---

> **dmesg | tail**
> [108513.254296] device eth2 entered promiscuous mode
> [108513.390125] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready
> [108513.410895] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): xenbr2: link is not ready

---

> **ifconfig eth2**
> eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 00:26:b9:46:61:1d
> ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
> Paquetes RX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
> Paquetes TX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
> colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
> Bytes RX:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
> **Interrupción:16**

---

I have tried adding the following lines to **sysctl:**

> net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
> net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
> net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1

No joy there...

Does anyone know where I am messing up? 
Cheers for the help!

Comment: Did you plug in a network cable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a driver issue.
Compiled ethernet drivers from compat-drivers and it worked. 
https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Releases

Answer (score 1):

Apparently that switch does not work (with today kernels). You have to disable ipv6 for every single interface individually.

Comment: net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1<br>
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1<br>
net.ipv6.conf.eth2.disable_ipv6 = 1<br>
No joy there either